# How can I save the name of the selected option?

Tags: django

How can I save the name of the selected option in a select input? If i select plan and i sumbit i want to in select option stay plan option not selected option.

```
<form method="get">
     
          <!-- filtro por carpeta -->
      <label for="carpeta">Carpeta</label>
         <select id="carpeta" class="form-control" name="carpeta">
             <option disabled selected>Selecciona una opcion</option>
             <option>Plan</option>
             <option>Gestion</option>
           </select>
         <br />
            {% block buscador %}
            Nombre:<br /> <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ request.GET.buscar }}" name="buscar" />
          <br />
        {% endblock buscador %}
              <!-- fin filtro por carpeta -->  
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Buscar</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a very simple solution.

```
<form method="get">

<!-- filtro por carpeta -->
<label for="carpeta">Carpeta</label>
<select id="carpeta" class="form-control" name="carpeta">
    <option disabled {% if not request.GET.carpeta %}selected{% endif %}>Selecciona
        una opcion
    </option>
    <option {% if request.GET.carpeta == 'Plan' %}selected{% endif %}>Plan</option>
    <option {% if request.GET.carpeta == 'Gestion' %}selected{% endif %}>Gestion
    </option>
</select>
<br/>

<!-- fin filtro por carpeta -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Buscar</button>
```

Or you can use django form.